# Identify the excel addin being used using a VBA Macro

Tags: excel, vba

I am working with Excel and we are using an Excel Addin to perform some of the calculations that we may need. The add-in has various formulae. What I am trying to do is write a VBA macro that will identify any formulae from the add-in being used in the sheet and paste them as values. Is there any way the macro can identify which formulae are linked to the add-in and which of those are plain excel formulae?

Answer (score 0):

It is not ideal especially if your add-ins have many functions. But basically you can create a table with 2 columns, `AddinName`, `FunctionName`. And then you can loops through cells check if a cell has formula using the `Range.HasFormula`. And then check if any of the functions you have in the table you created is in that cell.